# Specify 'html, body' css settings with Meteor for specific page/route

Tags: javascript, html, css, meteor, iron-router

I'm trying to adjust some page background css settings for a specific route/page in my Meteor app. I was able to do so by using Template.template.rendered/destroyed and jQuery selectors to inject the css once the template is rendered, like so:

```
Template.template.rendered = function() {
  $('html, body').css({
    "background-color": "#fdfdfd",
    ...additional css properties
  };
};

Template.template.destroyed = function() {
  $('html, body').css({
    "background": "none"
  };
};
```

I was wondering if anyone knew of a better way to do this. It seems a little slow, and when returning to the page using the back button on the browser, the page seems to freeze for about 5 seconds. Is using the iron-router before/after hooks any better? I'm not too familiar with them, but the slowness seems to be a browser issue. My thinking is the before/after hooks would help fix this. Are there any other options besides these two methods? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you *really, really* need to be attaching styling directly to the `html` and `body` elements in a way which is specific to certain pages, I'd strongly recommend wrapping each entire page in a div with `width: 100vw;` and `height: 100vh;` and appropriate `id`s, and then using the latter to style directly with css.

If you *do* need to attach directly to the `html` and `body` elements, have you tried to do this with an `onAfterAction` hook in iron-router?  Seems like a better place for it given that the styling depends on the route, not the template (even though Blaze means you can probably get away with what you're doing).

Comment: The issue was with using Meteor's template system, which, with all CSS being global, causes some problems when you want one page to be styled completely differently from another. I was wanting to use a common layoutTemplate, but I don't really see a way to achieve that, so I ended up creating a new one with the div like you suggested.

Comment: Bear in mind you could still use a common layout,  but use a template helper to add a class to the global container div depending on which route is being rendered. Then you can still just apply custom styling to those classes. Let me know if you need an example and I'll provide one later.

Comment: Thanks, but this is going to be for an entire section of the site. So it will actually be for several pages (eventually). I am thinking using a layoutTemplate and specifying it in iron-router for each route would be the cleanest.